# Angular ui-router not loading views

Tags: angularjs

I seem to have an issue getting ui-router to actually route things. I am sure that all of my javascript files are being loaded and angular isn't throwing any errors. I have an HTML file that declares the app and controller and then I load the js file that has the router. You can see my code on given link.
https://github.com/ikshit1/testProject

Comment: I'm not sure you can load your app files inside the body tag, since it has a ng-controller call. Have you tried moving all of your js in the head tag, just to see if it works?

Comment: On a side note. All your files being loaded and angular not throwing errors is not a guarantee that angular has been loaded properly.

Comment: Thanks Christian for your reply but I found the problem was in my routing file. I declared my state as 
.state('app.dashboard', {
          url: '/app/dashboard',
          templateUrl: '/public/view/dashboard.html'
        })
So,I just changed the url to /dashboard  and it worked for me.@Christian Bonato

Comment: Yes, common error when you start working with ui-router. All URLs are relative to index.html, and therefore the folder where index.html resides. Glad you found. Angular gets easier the more you code it.

Comment: yeah true @Christian Bonato

Answer (score 0):

In your main index.html file make sure you have 
 `<main ui-view></main>`